# NodeJS problem getting multiple query results simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, arrays, express

It's my first project using NodeJS, and I'm trying to fetch all posts in all groups in which the user is a member. And as such, I'm trying to put all the data into and array before calling the **res.send** method. However, the array is empty at the end (pardon the naming of tables as I used french).

```
router.get('/getUserPostes/:userId', async (req, res) => {
    let userId = req.params.userId;
    let endResult = []
    await db.query('select groupeId from groupemembers where userId = ?', userId, async function(err, result){
        if (err){
            console.log(err.message)
            res.send(null)
        }
        else {
            await result.map(async groupe => {
                await db.query('select * from postes where groupeId = ?', groupe.groupeId, function(err, result){
                    if (result != []){
                        endResult.push(result)
                    }
                })
            })
            res.send(endResult)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: `await result.map()` does not do what you want because you're awaiting an array (since `.map()` return an array) not a promise.  You could do `await Promise.all(result.map(...))`

Comment: Also, `await db.query()` also does not do anything useful because you're also passing a callback.  If you pass a callback, then it does NOT return a promise.  Please don't just go cramming an `await` everywhere without understanding how you're precisely awaiting a promise since that's the only thing it is useful to `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `.map` is not an asynchronous function so you are essentially sending you're response before the queries within `.map` are complete. Assuming your DB library supports promises, something like this would be more clean:

```
router.get('/getUserPostes/:userId', async (req, res) => {
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  try {
    const result = await db.query('select groupeId from groupemembers where userId = ?', userId)

    const endResult = await Promise.all(result.map(groupe => {
      return db.query('select * from postes where groupeId = ?', groupe.groupeId)
    }))
    res.send(endResult)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
  }
})
```

Bear in mind that there is likely a single query that you can pull this data with. However, without knowing the DB schema, it would be difficult for me to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

`await result.map()` does not do what you want because you're awaiting an array (since `.map()` return an array) not a promise.  You could do `await Promise.all(result.map(...))` or change to a `for` loop and `await` each individual request.

Also, `await db.query()` also does not do anything useful because you're also passing a callback.  If you pass a callback, then it does NOT return a promise.  Please don't just go cramming an `await` everywhere without understanding how you're precisely awaiting a promise since that's the only thing it is useful to `await`.

And, if this is mysql, then you will want a nodejs driver for mysql that supports promises so you can do it this way:

```
router.get('/getUserPostes/:userId', async (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.params.userId;
    try {
        const endResult = [];
        const result = await db.query('select groupeId from groupemembers where userId = ?', userId);
        for (const groupe of result) {
            let groupResult = await db.query('select * from postes where groupeId = ?', groupe.groupeId);
            if (groupResult) {
                endResult.push(groupResult);
            }
        }
        res.send(endResult);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

To use promises with mysql, there are a number of ways to get promise support.  One such way is to use the mysql2 module and do this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
```